# Handling dots of ellipsis

Tags: css

I'm new to css, I'm showing list of actions as links on a actions bar.
Whenever list of actions are increased I need to show ... as a sufix of buttons,
I could do this with the following code snippet

```
<div class="actions-menu" style="width:200px; height: 30px;display: inline-block;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">
```

this is giving me action1 action2 action3 ...
now when I click on ... I need to show remaining actions on a dropdown here I'm struggling, how to handle these ..., how to click on that is my question, please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tabindex + focus can help ... untill focus is lost

```css
ul, li {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  height:1.2em;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  }
ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  background:turquoise
  }
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background:tomato;
  }
/*reset ellipsis rules */
ul:focus {
  overflow:visible;
  }
ul:focus li {
  display:block;
  overflow:visible;
  white-space:normal;
  height:auto;
  }
ul li:hover {
  background:lime;
  }
```

```html
<p>test</p>
<ul tabindex="0">
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. test</p>
```

[a toggle css example](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Kakge) ... still javascript should be used

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't really possible in CSS alone. What you'd probably want to do is wire up some JavaScript to toggle a class on that element whenever it is clicked.

```
<script>
  // jQuery
  $('.actions-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
</script>
<style>
  .actions-menu.open {overflow: visible !important;}
</style>
```

If you're dead-set on using only CSS, then adding this will probably be the best that can be done, but it only works while the mouse button is down.

```
<style>
.actions-menu:active {overflow: visible !important;}
</style>
```